# dart polymer: unable to get input from array

Tags: dart, polymer

i try to get some input from an array of maps using dart/polymer:

```
@CustomTag('attrib-form')
class AttribForm extends PolymerElement  {
   @observable List attrs = toObservable([]);
   created() {
       super.created();
   }

   init(attrs) {
      this.attrs = attrs;
   }

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<polymer-element name="attrib-form">

    <template if="{{attrs.length>0}}">

        <template repeat="{{attr in attrs}}">
            <div>
            <div>{{attr['name']}}</div>
              <input id="{{attr['name']}}" type="text" value="{{attr['value']}}">
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="attrib_form.dart"></script>

</polymer-element>


main() {
    var attrib = [
        {"name": "name", "value": "a"}, 
        {"name": "type", "value": "b"}, 
        {"name": "width","value": "c"}];
    var form = createElement('attrib-form');
    var x = form.xtag; 
    x.init(attrib);
}
```

the form is showing fine with all the correct values, but i am unable to change the input values. i can neither add nor delete from the input fields.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@observable List attrs` just makes the variable `attrs` observable. If you set `attr` to a different list the template will display the new list.

`= toObservable([]);` just makes the list itself observable. Adding a new item to the list will display in the template. It does not affect the `attrs` variable or changes to the elements in the list.

You need to make your `attrib` `map` observable. The problem is the value of the input is bound to the map, but the two way data binding doesn't work since the value in the map is not observable. Changing the value of the input must trigger the observer which sets the value back to what it is in the map. Making the map observable will make the value of the input change the value in the map.

To make the map observable, use the same `toObservable()` function that you used on the list.

```
import "package:observe/observe.dart";

int main()
    var attrib = toObservable([
        {"name": "name", "value": "a"}, 
        {"name": "type", "value": "b"}, 
        {"name": "width","value": "c"}]);
    var form = createElement('attrib-form');
    var x = form.xtag; 
    x.init(attrib);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly now. this one was driving me crazy. dart /polymer is very promising. i like it a lot. but being under heavy development, documentation sometimes is not so easy to find ...